# Heroku Django-Admin 500 Error?

Tags: django, deployment, heroku, django-admin

Deployed a new app to Heroku app that runs fine at myapp.herokuapp.com, but throws a 500 Server Error if I try to access the admin backend at myapp.herokuapp.com/admin

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'gunicorn',
    'storages',
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',

)
```

Here's the log excerpt:

```
2013-07-10T17:35:28.893320+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python manage.py run_gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:27294 -w 3 --log-level info`
2013-07-10T17:35:32.298226+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-07-10 13:35:32 [2] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 0.17.4
2013-07-10T17:35:32.299005+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-07-10 13:35:32 [2] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2013-07-10T17:35:32.298932+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-07-10 13:35:32 [2] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:27294 (2)
2013-07-10T17:35:32.312781+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-07-10 13:35:32 [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
2013-07-10T17:35:32.388874+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-07-10 13:35:32 [12] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 12
2013-07-10T17:35:32.495370+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2013-07-10T17:35:32.524196+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-07-10 13:35:32 [13] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 13
2013-07-10T17:35:59.929850+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=myapp.herokuapp.com fwd="64.119.130.116" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=190ms status=200 bytes=12220
2013-07-10T17:36:04.363323+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/admin host=myapp.herokuapp.com fwd="64.119.130.116" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=301 bytes=5
2013-07-10T17:36:04.872523+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/admin/ host=myapp.herokuapp.com fwd="64.119.130.116" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=481ms status=500 bytes=38
```

What settings would cause the app to run normally but throw a 500 error on /admin? What am I likely overlooking or missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Magnus' recommendation I added sentry to my project and identified a postgres DatabaseError: relation issue due a project app I hadn't successfully migrated on heroku.

Fix just took a fake and completing the rest of the migration.

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate app 0016 --fake
heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 4):

- You can add free [getsentry](https://addons.heroku.com/sentry) addon and receive exception traceback remaining in `DEBUG=False` in production.
- You can also setup plain email notification on errors as admin email.

Without any information about error details it will be hard to give you advice.

Comment: Magnus, awesome recommendation on Sentry - hadn't used it previously. Was able to diagnose my own issue (needed to run a production db migration for postgres)

Comment: For those coming here now, the Sentry add-on isn't free. It starts at $29 / month.